# Remove time from date/time view in SharePoint List with Json

Tags: json, list, sharepoint, view, format

i have included a list in sharepoint that serves as a team calendar in a teams channel. Unfortunately, only the name of the person should be displayed, but not the time (start of vacation). The original field is date/time but cannot be changed, otherwise the flow will not work. I can only change the view and only want the date to be displayed.

[Start of vacation field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt5kZ.png)

[Only the name should be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7xbX.png)

I've already tried some json snippets, but I can't get it to work, can you help me?

Comment: Are you using calendar view in list? How you added calendar in a teams channel?

Comment: I pasted the entire SharePoint site into the Teams channel